# Pointer reference to a nullptr?

Tags: c++

I think this question should have been posted on Stack Overflow, but as I am using all of this stuff to make a video game, I decided to post it here.

So, suppose you have an integer value called '*firstgid*' declared:

```
int firstgid;
```

And I'm not telling the program what value `firstgid` equals to, like I'm not saying that `int firstgid = 5;` or something.

And then somewhere else in the program, I say:

```
SDL_Texture* tex(graphics, &firstgid);
```

Notice the `&firstgid` here. I am not telling the program what `firstgid` is, and still I am making a reference to it using the ampersand
(`&`) symbol.

So, if I do that, will the program crash and display this breakpoint error on the output screen?:

```
Unhandled exception thrown. Read access violation:
  **this** was nullptr
```

A good folk just told me that the `**this** was nullptr` breakpoint error is triggered when we are calling a *function* on an unknown *value* or stuff.

What do you guys think about it?
 Thank you for your kind assistance.

Comment: Not sure if this is game related but just your usual stackoverflow question.

Comment: This does really belong on stackoverflow, not here.  That being said, what does the "tex" function do?  What you did isn't *technically* illegal in C++, but may cause something inside of `tex` to suffer an exception like this.  It's also possible that you failed to initialize a library.

Comment: @CortAmmon. Don't worry about tex. It's not a function, it's a variable. What I mean is-- I am doing a pointer reference to firstgid in this statement. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: @Aditya Chandra could you please explain how is `tex` a variable?

Comment: @CortAmmon SDL_Texture is a function that is defining a variable called 'tex', for further functionality, using the asterisk (*).

Comment: @AdityaChandra I see what's going on now.  I was confused because that error message didn't look "standard" to me, so I thought it might be an error deep inside the SDL.  Answer in comming

Comment: @CortAmmon That's okay. I meant to be universal This SDL stuff are just examples.

Comment: If you really wanted to make it generic, you would have used something other than an SDL example, and you would have supplied the code of what SDL_Texture does with your use case. And you would have asked it on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, pointers are a very important concept.  In this case, they get a bit confusing because they're pointing to an unspecified integer, so let's get the rules about unspecified values out of the way.

The specific line from the specification is section 8.5.11:

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized; if no initialization is performed, an
>   **object with automatic or dynamic storage duration has indeterminate value**.

What that last bit means is that your integer, `firstgid`, has an unspecified value because you did not assign one.  It might be 0.  It might be 1.  It might be -1195716.  It might even be different each time you run the program.  It is *legal* to access this value, it's just not specified what its value will be.  *If* it were a pointer, it would be a pointer to an unspecified memory address, so *dereferencing* it would be illegal, but `firstgid` is not a pointer, it's an `int`.

A key thing to note is that you can *always* assign a value to a variable that previously had an unspecified value.  If you were to later write `firstgid = 1`, that would be completely valid *and* `firstgid` would have a defined value from that point on (it's value would be `1`).

Now for the pointers.  The `&` operator is known as the "address of" operator.  It takes any variable and returns the address of that variable as a pointer.  In your case, because `firstgid` is an `int`, `&firstgid` will be an `int*`.  The value of this pointer (the address) is defined, even if the value of the integer it is pointing at is not.  The important thing here is that the pointer is valid, and we can dereference it.  For example:

```
int firstgid; // an int with an unspecified value
int* ptr = &firstgid; // a pointer with a specified value (pointing at firstgid)

int temp1 = *ptr; // dereferencing the pointer to an unspecified value is valid,
                 // but the value of temp itself is unspecified
*ptr = 1; // assigning a value to the int that ptr points to
int temp2 = firstgid; // temp2 is now 1
```

So, in this case, you can pass `&firstgid` to `tex()`, as long as `tex()` operates correctly if the pointer is a pointer to an unspecified value.

The specific error you mention is what happens when you try to call a method on an object that you got by derefereincing a null pointer:

```
MyObject* objPtr = nullptr; // create a new pointer, not pointing at anything
objPtr->foo(); // ERROR!  **this** was nullptr
```

The difference between your first case and this second one is that, in the first case, you had a perfectly valid pointer, it was just pointing to an object with an unspecified value.  In the second case, we're actually calling a member function from a null pointer.  Pointers must be pointing at a valid object if you want to use them to call member functions on the object they point at.  However, this is fine:

```
MyObject* objPtr = nullptr;
someFunction(objPtr);
```

In this case, all we did was pass a null pointer to `someFunction`, which is legal, as long as `someFunction` is ready for it.  For example, it might have some code like:

```
void someFunction(MyObject* obj)
{
    // If the user does not provide an object, use the default one
    if (obj == nullptr)
        obj = sDefaultObject;
    ...
}
```

In this case, objPtr will not change (because the *pointer* to the object was copied as part of the function call), but clearly `someFunction` will operate on some other object.

Comment: Thank you, Ammon. This answer will not only aid me now, it will be helpful in the future as well.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't **access**/**use** `firstgid` before initializing it, there's no problem at all with that. Check if the function which is receiving a reference to it is not using it.

By using it I mean calling a function on the object, using its value (which is not necessarily bad, the only problem is that you don't know what value it holds) or trying to dereference it if it were a pointer.

Comment: +1, good answer, but I just wanted to quickly add that it's okay to assign to the integer inside the function: `*firstgid = 42;`, since it's actually reserved space and not equal to `nullptr`.

Comment: @Tyyppi_73 : Hi, Tyyppi_73. The 'good folk' I talked about in my question is you.

Comment: @Tyyppi_73 : Can we tell the program what the value of 'firstgid' is inside a function using '*'?

Comment: Yes, that will change the value of the integer outside of the function call too. That's how multiple return values are sometimes implemented, using pointers.

Comment: You can't change the value of a non-pointer variable using `*`. It will give you a dereferencing error. If you want to assign it you must use `firstgid = value`

Comment: I was under the impression we were talking about the function which takes in an integer pointer (`&firstgid`) which would make changing it possible.

Comment: Excuse me. I missunderstood. That's right. Using `*` is the way of changing outside's value too. If you don't use the `*`, you will be changing the pointer itself, but it's just a copy of the pointer